# Multiple execution by apache httpclient

Tags: java, http, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

So here is the thing, I need to access a very busy site which i cannot access with only a single request.

So what I want is to make multiple requests for a same web-address using Apache HttpClient or other good library of java and wait for a successful response form the site. Once a request get a successful response all other request in the thread need to terminated immediately.

How can I do it? Also if there is other good library available for the task please let me know.

Comment: You essentially want to DOS the site which leads to the site being more busy than it needs to.  Sounds unethical.

Comment: If I want to DOS the site I would simply use a number of threads instead stop it after a successful response.@JoseMartinez

Comment: You may be able to stop your code from waiting for the response, but the server will continue chugging along wasting resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to use single thread and retry if some error occurs. This way you will not flood the busy site. This will not be much slower, because if the server's busy, making more requests will not give you any advantage.
If you decide to use multiple threads anyway (use 2), all the threads needs to share the same HTTP client:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = createDefault();
```

When you receive successful response you will have to call

```
 httpclient.close();
```

and stop all the threads. The `close()` will terminate all the connections (active and inactive).

Comment: Thank you. Now its clear to me. btw if I increase the timeout will this help?

Comment: Yes, if the server/connection is slow increasing the timeout will help more :)